# How to specify PST time zone in @Scheduled annotation that should trigger every hour between 7AM PST to 6 PM PST?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks

My Java Web application has a Cron Job Scheduler which should trigger every hour starting from **7AM PST to 6PM PST**. I am not getting how to specify **PST time zone** using  **zone** parameter inside @Scheduled annotation. Kindly help

```
  @Component
  public class CronJobForFailedLoans {

      @Scheduled(cron ="0 0 7-18 ? * *")
     public void cronJobForFailedLoans()  {
    // Perform operations

 }  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `cron` expression is valid just use `Zone` to specify the timezone, use online [cron](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) for validating and generating cron expression

```
@Scheduled(cron ="0 0 7-18 ? * *", zone="America/Los_Angeles")
```

Comment: If I want to trigger the job for every 30 mintues between 7AM & 6PM PST , then which one is correct?  1.  **@Scheduled(cron ="0 0/30 7-18 ? * *", zone="America/Los_Angeles") **                or                                                                               2.  **@Scheduled(cron ="0 */30 7-18 ? * *", zone="America/Los_Angeles")**

Comment: I tried with @Scheduled(cron ="0 0/30 3-4 ? * *", zone="America/Los_Angeles") , But the Job got triggered at 4.30 PM PST. Can somebody help me perfect answer. ?

Comment: use this one `0 30 7-18 ? * *` @Karthiksa